# Code not run on huge dataset

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is the code , which run on my system , code is working fine , with small amount of data , but the same code is not working with huge amount of dataset or text files , Yes @ennikiller is Right , some files are empty (mean they have no `Esgn` values but they have other values) , I want to handle it as , it should assign zero to `Esgn` or just count minimum from all other values and leave about `Esgn` (In that particular file which not contain `Esgn` not for all)

```
    import os.path
    import glob
    import re
    import itertools
    from collections import namedtuple, deque
    from operator import attrgetter

    R_PREFIX_VALUE = re.compile(r'^(?P<prefix>[A-Z]+)(?P<suffix>\d+)\s+(?P<value>\d+)\s*$')

    getvalue  = attrgetter('value')

    def interleave(seq, val):
        return itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.izip(seq, itertools.repeat(val)))

    class Fileline(namedtuple('Fileline', 'filename prefix suffix value')):
        @classmethod
        def _fromstr(cls, s, filename=None, rematch=R_PREFIX_VALUE.match):
            m = rematch(s)
            if not m:
                raise ValueError('No valid line found in %r' % s)
            d = m.groupdict()
            d['value'] = int(d['value'])
            d['filename'] = filename
            return cls(**d)

        def _asstr(self):
            return '{}{} {}'.format(self.prefix, self.suffix, self.value)

    def max_value_with_prefix(lineseq, prefix, getvalue=getvalue):
        withprefix = (line for line in lineseq if line.prefix==prefix)
        return max_value(withprefix)

    def filter_lt_line(lineseq, maxline):
        for line in lineseq:
            if line.prefix != maxline.prefix or line.value >= maxline.value:
                yield line

    def extreme_value(fn, lineseq, getvalue=getvalue):
        try:
            return fn((l for l in lineseq if l is not None), key=getvalue)
        except ValueError:
            return None

    def max_value(lineseq):
        return extreme_value(max, lineseq)

    def min_value(lineseq):
        return extreme_value(min, lineseq)

    def read_lines(fn, maker=Fileline._fromstr):
        with open(fn, 'rb') as f:
            return deque(maker(l, fn) for l in f)

    def write_file(fn, lineseq):
        lines = (l._asstr() for l in lineseq)
        newlines = interleave(lines, '\n')
        with open(fn, 'wb') as f:
            f.writelines(newlines)

    def write_output_file(fn, lineseq):
        lines = ("{} {}".format(l.filename, l.value) for l in lineseq)
        newlines = interleave(lines, "\n")
        with open(fn, 'wb') as f:
            f.writelines(newlines)

    def filter_max_returning_min(fn, prefix):
        lineseq = read_lines(fn)
        maxvalue = max_value_with_prefix(lineseq, prefix)
        filteredlineseq = deque(filter_lt_line(lineseq, maxvalue))
        write_file(fn, filteredlineseq)
        minline = min_value(filteredlineseq)
        return minline

    def main(fileglob, prefix, outputfile):
        minline = None
        for fn in glob.iglob(fileglob):
            fileminline = filter_max_returning_min(fn, prefix)
            minline = min_value([minline, fileminline])
        write_output_file(outputfile, [minline])
    def _worker(args):
        return filter_max_returning_min(*args)

    """def multi_main(fileglob, prefix, outputfile, processes):
        from multiprocessing import Pool
        pool = Pool(processes=processes)
        workerargs = ((fn, prefix) for fn in glob.iglob(fileglob))
        minlines = pool.imap_unordered(_worker, workerargs, processes)
        minline = min_value(minlines)
        write_file(outputfile, [minline])"""
    def main(fileglob, prefix, outputfile):
        minlines = []
        for fn in glob.iglob(fileglob):
            minlines.append(filter_max_returning_min(fn, prefix))
        write_output_file(outputfile, minlines)
    main('C:\Python27\DataSet\*.txt', 'ENSG', 'output.txt')
```

This is my code , this code is working fine on 10/20 text files , but when i run it 3000 txt files it give me the following error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Ir\Desktop\S_Project\Finding_min_val_and_escaping_'Esgn'\dataset_code.py", line 95, in <module>
        main('C:\Python27\DataSet\*.txt', 'ENSG', 'output.txt')
      File "C:\Users\Ir\Desktop\S_Project\Finding_min_val_and_escaping_'Esgn'\dataset_code.py", line 93, in main
        minlines.append(filter_max_returning_min(fn, prefix))
      File "C:\Users\Ir\Desktop\S_Project\Finding_min_val_and_escaping_'Esgn'\dataset_code.py", line 69, in filter_max_returning_min
        filteredlineseq = deque(filter_lt_line(lineseq, maxvalue))
      File "C:\Users\Ir\Desktop\S_Project\Finding_min_val_and_escaping_'Esgn'\dataset_code.py", line 35, in filter_lt_line
        if line.prefix != maxline.prefix or line.value >= maxline.value:
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'prefix'
lines = ("{} {}".format(l.filename, l.value) for l in lineseq)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filename'
```

Comment: The issue is not with the number of files, but with the actual data.  Try to figure out which particular file is causing the problem.  Somewhere, the data does not have the form you think it does.

Comment: No , i have 3000 text files, how to check them :)

Comment: @BrenBarn Is it possible that first i make all 3000 files `,` seprated , than i check that if there is any file which is empty or not , and than run my code

Comment: try/except ... divide and conquer ... etc

Comment: Just put some print statements in to print out the filename, then you can see what file it fails on.

Comment: @BrenBarn Where to put statement ?

Comment: Im curious how you got this code as far as you did ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley English is not my mother tongue , so am so so so so sorry , if it hurts you , i may not getting the points of you people

Comment: @ActingAngel no its not the language ... I dont have a problem with that ... but i suspect you just copied this code from somewhere without understanding it... you are asking where you can print the filename and where to put code (that is very similar to existing code)

Comment: @JoranBeasley Yes , because the answer of @ennukiller are edited twice , and it have mistakes , so i thought he add some thing new , thats y i asked this , it still have `milline` and before it , it was `neseq` as function name

Comment: well I am happy that it sounds like you have now resolved the issue :) hopefully you find the problem :) (but lets avoid extended discussions in comments)

Answer (score 0):

try printing out the values of line and maxline

Clearly one or the other is being set to None.  Most probably it is maxline, if fact it definitely is.  So find out why you are passing None for maxline.  So you should really be looking here:

```
try:
    lineseq = read_lines(fn)
    maxvalue = max_value_with_prefix(lineseq, prefix)
    filteredlineseq = deque(filter_lt_line(lineseq, maxvalue))
    write_file(fn, filteredlineseq)
    minline = min_value(filteredlineseq)
except:
    print "%s is apparently empty" % fn
    minline = None
finally:
    return milline
```

Is it possible that fn is an empty file?

As Joran states, you simply need to add some exception processing (I've added it above)

Comment: what do you mean you cant check ... put in a try/except and find which one is causing the problem ...

Comment: @ennuikiller Where to put your code in my code ? in which method?

Comment: the place in your code that looks very similar already? did you actually write this code or did you just copy/paste it? ... anyway put it in the method named filter_max_returning_min

Comment: @JoranBeasley What do you mean by this ?

Comment: I mean look at your method named filter_max_returning_min .... and compare it with the code above ...

Comment: @ennuikiller its minline not milline , The files which it shows empty , are not empty , it contain data , but they have no `ESGN` value , `ESGN` is not in txt files , +1 for answer